# Calling a function in one JS file in many other JS files

Tags: javascript, rhino

I am new to JavaScript and Rhino.
I have many JavaScript files that have identical functions.
I wish to create a new js file and put all the frequently used functions in it and call these functions in other js files.
Is this possible in Rhino ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you define the functions in the global scope, you can use them in other js files.

Answer (score 0):

a good way to call functions across different files would be to make a global object then make the functions properties of that object example: 
var myObj = {
 thefirst1:function(){
 //some code
},
thesecond1:function(){
 //some code
}
}

then call it like this myObj.thesecond1()

Comment: let's suppose I put var myObj = { thefirst1:function(){ //some code }, thesecond1:function(){ //some code } } in myFirst.js(Rhino js file) , then in mySecond.js all I need to do is myObj.thesecond1 , is that correct? If yes it's so simple and thanks again for the help.

Comment: yep you got it, but remember: the file that contains your global object should be loaded first(so its read first) and don't forget the parenthesis "()"

Comment: @muhammad abdul aleem if the answer is what you're were looking for could you please except it(check mark) thanks

Comment: How do I make sure that it's loaded first ?

Comment: disregard that loaded first comment. you should be fine just so long as your object/functions are global

Comment: I read the contents of the helper file ,appended to the actual file and used Context.compileString()